# Tomcat 7 + Maven 3 Deployment Plugin - Step by Step

Tags: java, plugins, maven-3, tomcat7, web-deployment

I researched a lot about tomcat-maven-plugin. I do not have exact steps on how to do the integration.

I tried changing tomcat-users.xml, pom.xml, settings.xml and also added a goal in Configurations.

Can anyone explain in step by step manner what to do?

I am using Maven 3 and Tomcat 7 along with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use ant run plugin that will copy WAR file to tomcat's webapps directory.
http://www.itcuties.com/tools/maven-3-deploy-war-package/